# Python sort runs in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve an example in my book:

Write a program that generates a sequence of 20 random die tosses in a list and that prints the die values, marking the runs by including them in parentheses, like this:

1 2 (5 5) 3 1 2 4 3 (2 2 2 2) 3 6 (5 5) 6 3 1

Use the following pseudocode:

```
Set a boolean variable inRun to false. 

For each valid index i in the list 

   If inRun 

      If values[i] is different from the preceding value 

         Print). 
         inRun = false. 

   If not inRun 

       If values[i] is the same as the following value 

         Print (. 
         inRun = true. 

   Print values[i]. 

If inRun, print).
```

Here is my code:

```
import random

min = 1
max = 6

randomToss = []

for i in range(20):
    randomToss.append(random.randint(min, max))

print(randomToss)



inRun = False

for i in randomToss:
    if inRun:
        if randomToss[i] != i - 1:
            print(")")
            inRun = False
    if not inRun:
        if randomToss[i] == i + 1:
            print("(")
            inRun = True
        print(randomToss[i])
if inRun:
    print(")")
```

When it runs, I get an output like so:

[2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 5, 1, 6, 4]

1
(
4
)
5
3
5
1
1
1
(
4
)
1
1
5
1
5
1
1
(
4
)
5
(
4
)
1

When it should look something like:
[2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 5, 1, 6, 4]

2 5 1 3 1 (4 4 4) 6 4 2 1 4 1 (4 4) 5 1 6 4

What is wrong?

Comment: Part of a [MCVE] is providing the actual and expected outputs, not just "it doesn't sort them how I want". Please provide the expected outputs; for reproducible results, you might insert a `random.seed(1)` before you begin rolling so you always roll the same sequence of rolls.

Comment: `if randomToss[i] != i - 1` compares `randomToss[i]` to the actual value `i - 1`, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: @JohnGordon that makes sense. What would be the proper move in this case then?

Comment: `if randomToss[i] != randomToss[i - 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `for i in randomToss:` and then doing `randomToss[i]`. This is wrong. `i` here refers to the *actual value* in the array and **not** the *index*.

you should use the `range` function to generate the indices for iteration.

```
for i in range(len(randomToss) - 1):     # <- returns the indeices 
    if inRun:
        if randomToss[i] != randomToss[i + 1]:
            print(randomToss[i], end='') # <- you must print the number before ')'
            print(")", end='')
            inRun = False
    else:                                # use else since you're changing isRun inside the loop 
        if randomToss[i] == randomToss[i + 1]:
            print("(", end='')
            inRun = True
        print(randomToss[i], end='')
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. I didn't realize that i was the actual value vs the index. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is wrong with your current code. You have an array of integers called randomToss.You are looping over each integer in the array, when you do this, you set a variable called i, which stands for the index of the array.

```
[1 2 5 5 3, 1] // array 
[1 2 3 4 5, 6] // index values
```

The index is the current array element in incremental order, 1,2,3.... While inside this loop you are checking the current integer, randomToss[i], in the array to the value of the the index value. You need to check the next and previous array elements. To do this you can use the index to get the element out of the array by adding or subtracting one (remember incremental) .

```
for i in range(len(randomToss)-1):
    if inRun:
        if randomToss[i] != randomToss[i-1]:
            print(")")
            inRun = False
    if not inRun:
        if randomToss[i] == randomToss[i+1]:
            print("(")
            inRun = True
        print(randomToss[i])
```

Comment: You're doing the same mistake! `for i in randomToss:` returns the value and not the index

Comment: Oh, my bad. Though i added the range function, guess i should have just edited straight in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works.

```
import random

min = 1
max = 6

randomToss = []

for i in range(20):
    randomToss.append(random.randint(min, max))

print(randomToss)



inRun = False

for i in range(20): # i is the index not the value
    if inRun:
        if i != 0 and randomToss[i] != randomToss[i - 1]: # check boundary conditions and compare the values
            print(")", end="")
            inRun = False
    if not inRun:
        if i != 19 and randomToss[i] == randomToss[i + 1]: # check boundary conditions and compare the values
            print("(", end="")
            inRun = True
    print(randomToss[i], end="") # check indentation with the pseudocode
if inRun:
    print(")", end="")
```